# How to get 4 by 4 bounding boxes of an image and their corresponding coordinaates?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying get 4 by 4 bounding boxes of an image. Like this bounding box

[Bounding Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOxZk.png)

Can someone please help me how to get those bounding boxes and their coordinates?

Comment: You'll need to scan the image and once the color changes mark the location, I'm not sure i understood what you meant

Comment: @benor hi i want to read an image and draw 4 by 4 bounding boxes and their coordinates also.

Comment: How do you determine where the boxes are drawn?

Comment: @BlueRineS Think of the photo as a rectangle and the bounding boxes will be the 4 equal parts.

Comment: Please provide some proper input images, and the corresponding expected output images (maybe drawn by hand). By now, it's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to draw the lines on the image? Or cut the image along the lines?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i want to draw lines on the image and get the coordinates.

Comment: A *"bounding box"* normally encloses, or shows the boundaries of a specific object or objects. Your boxes seem to, somewhat arbitrarily, divide the image into 4 regardless of objects so they seem incorrectly named. Or are you failing to tell us something about your images?

Comment: @MarkSetchell hey i have updated the question image please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to visually split the input image to 4 squares. In this case all you need is to draw two lines: one horizontal, one vertical. see [Drawing Functions in OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html). 
A quick example:

```py
import cv2

height, width = input_image.shape[:2]

# for horizontal line
horizontal_left = (0, int(height / 2))
horizontal_right = (int(width), int(height / 2))

cv2.line(input_image, horizontal_left, horizontal_right, (0, 255, 0), 1)

# for vertical
vertical_top = (int(width / 2), 0)
vertical_bottom = (int(width / 2), int(height))

cv2.line(input_image, vertical_top, vertical_bottom, (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create and rectangle use this piece of code.

```
import cv2

cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)


x1,y1 ------
|          |
|          |
|          |
--------x2,y2
```

And if you want to draw your own ROI use this piece of code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

    # Select ROI
    r = cv2.selectROI(im)

    # Crop image
    imCrop = im[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]

    # Display cropped image
    cv2.imshow("Image", imCrop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank You. It was really helpful. How to get the coordinates ?